# Why does dlsym fail to find a function in a dynamically loaded library?

Tags: c++, c

Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10565120/704028) to the question about [compiling additional code at runtime in C or C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10564670/is-there-any-way-to-compile-additional-code-at-runtime-in-c-or-c) I prepared this main program

```
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // create library
    system ( "/usr/bin/gcc -fPIC -shared test.cpp -o libtest.so" );

    // load library        
    void* fLib = dlopen ( "./libtest.so", RTLD_LAZY );
    if ( !fLib ) {
        cerr << "Cannot open library: " << dlerror() << '\n';
    }

    if ( fLib ) {
        void ( *fn ) () = reinterpret_cast<void (*)()>(dlsym(fLib, "test"));

        if ( fn ) {
            fn();
        }
        dlclose ( fLib );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

That is supposed to compile "test.cpp" into a dynamic library `libtest.so` in the current directory, load the library, find the `test` function in the library and call this funciton, but it seems that `dlsym` can't find the function, even though it's there.

Here's the `test.cpp` file:

```
#include <iostream>

void test()
{
    std::cout << "TEST" << std::endl;
}
```

The `main.cpp` is compiled with

```
g++ -ldl main.cpp -o main
```

and when I execute it, nothing happens: the library is loaded but the `fn` pointer is not available, meaning the function hasn't been found in `libtest.so`.

If I look at the symbols in `libtest.so` with `nm -gD`, I see the test function:

```
nm -gD libtest.so 
                 U __cxa_atexit@@GLIBC_2.2.5
                 w __cxa_finalize@@GLIBC_2.2.5
                 w __gmon_start__
                 w _ITM_deregisterTMCloneTable
                 w _ITM_registerTMCloneTable
0000000000001139 T _Z4testv
                 U _ZNSolsEPFRSoS_E
                 U _ZNSt8ios_base4InitC1Ev
                 U _ZNSt8ios_base4InitD1Ev
                 U _ZSt4cout
                 U _ZSt4endlIcSt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIT_T0_ES6_
                 U _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc
```

and

```
c++filt  _Z4testv
test()
```

Why doesn't `dlsym` find `test()`? How can I make it find the test function?

Comment: I know what name mangling is (used c++filt to demangle the name in the question), how do I fix this? Is there something concrete I can use to make `dlsym` know the name is mangled?

Comment: Should I hardcode the mangled name? This doesn't sound like a solution that's stable :)

Comment: Thanks! Stable: what if the way the function name is mangled changes from one gcc version to the next?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is rather simple: Use [C language linkage](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/language_linkage) for exported symbols. Then they won't be mangled:

```
extern "C" void test()
{
    std::cout << "TEST" << std::endl;
}
```