# Is there a function I can call from C++ linked with LLVM to compile C++ code?

Tags: c++, llvm

I have linked LLVM to my C++ project as a library and I need to compile some other C++ code. Is there a LLVM function I can call to do this? Or do I have to modify the LLVM source code?

Comment: Highly related, if not a dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10564670/is-there-any-way-to-compile-additional-code-at-runtime-in-c-or-c

Comment: libllvm actually doesn't know how to compile C++. It's a backend. libclang provides the front end. You probably need to add a lot of custom coding on top of that. Perhaps just run (system, fork+exec, CreateProcess, whatever) a C++ compiler instead.